# How do I loop through tables to fill columns in another table in sql?

Tags: sql, loops, db2, hierarchical-data

So I currently have three tables in SQL:

`Table One`

| Name | Code 1 | Description 1 | Code 2 | Description 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple |  |  |  |  |
| Avacado |  |  |  |  |
| Cabbage |  |  |  |  |
| Cheese |  |  |  |  |

`Level 1 Hierarchy`

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A... | Fruit |
| C... | Food |

`Level 2 Hierarchy`

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Ap.. | Seed Fruit |
| Av.. | Stone Fruit |
| Ca.. | Vegetable |
| Ch.. | Dairy |

I'm trying to find an SQL query to loop through both hierarchy tables to fill `table one` like below. I've thought about using `LIKE` but there are too many hierarchy codes to manually go through them like that.

| Name | Code 1 | Description 1 | Code 2 | Description 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | A... | Fruit | Ap.. | Seed Fruit |
| Avacado | A... | Fruit | Av.. | Stone Fruit |
| Cabbage | C... | Food | Ca.. | Vegetable |
| Cheese | C... | Food | Ch.. | Dairy |

Answer (score 0):

There are Many ways we can do this you can use direct update as well or Use Cursor for the Select statement as follows and Update the 2 nd table

```
DECLARE 
    @product_name VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @list_price   DECIMAL;

DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        product_name, 
        list_price
    FROM 
        production.products;

OPEN cursor_product;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO 
    @product_name, 
    @list_price;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @product_name + CAST(@list_price AS varchar);
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO 
            @product_name, 
            @list_price;
      Update the table you want
    END;

CLOSE cursor_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH 
  T1 (Name) AS
  (
    VALUES
      'Apple'               
    , 'Avacado'                 
    , 'Cabbage'
    , 'Cheese'
  )
, L1 (Code, Description) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ('A...', 'Fruit')
    , ('C...', 'Food')
  )
, L2 (Code, Description) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ('Ap..', 'Seed Fruit')
    , ('Av..', 'Stone Fruit')
    , ('Ca..', 'Vegetable')
    , ('Ch..', 'Dairy')
  )
*/
SELECT 
  T1.Name
, L1.Code           AS Code1
, L1.Description    AS Description1
, L2.Code           AS Code2
, L2.Description    AS Description2
FROM T1
JOIN L1 ON T1.Name LIKE TRANSLATE (L1.Code, '', '.', '') || '%'
JOIN L2 ON T1.Name LIKE TRANSLATE (L2.Code, '', '.', '') || '%'
```

| NAME | CODE1 | DESCRIPTION1 | CODE2 | DESCRIPTION2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | A... | Fruit | Ap.. | Seed Fruit |
| Avacado | A... | Fruit | Av.. | Stone Fruit |
| Cabbage | C... | Food | Ca.. | Vegetable |
| Cheese | C... | Food | Ch.. | Dairy |